# Android Studio online shopping

Tags: java, android

I have this problem with this app. The does not show me the Items quantity and price, But they show the name of the item, and I don't have any errors when I run the up.Please give me an advice if you can.

The cartactivity code :

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.bartertrader.Model.Cart;
import com.example.bartertrader.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.example.bartertrader.ViewHolder.CartViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Button NextProcessBtn;
    private TextView txtTotalAmount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);


        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        NextProcessBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_process_btn);
        txtTotalAmount =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_price);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart>options=
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
                .setQuery(cartListRef.child("User View").child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                .child("Products"), Cart.class).build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart,  CartViewHolder> adapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Cart model) {

                holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                holder.txtProductQuantity.setText("Quantity =" + model.getQuantity());
                holder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price= " + model.getPrice() + "");


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_items_layout,parent,false);
                CartViewHolder holder = new CartViewHolder(view);
                return holder;
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

Cart class

```
    private String pid, pname, price , quantity ,discount;

    public Cart() {
    }

    public Cart(String pid, String pname, String price, String quantity, String dicount) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.pname = pname;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.dicount = dicount;

    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getDicount() {
        return dicount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.dicount = dicount;
    }


}
```

Cardviewholder class

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.bartertrader.Interface.ItemClickListner;
import com.example.bartertrader.R;

public class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView txtProductName, txtProductPrice, txtProductQuantity;
    private ItemClickListner itemClickListner;

    public CartViewHolder( View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_name);
        txtProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_price);
        txtProductQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_quantity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListner.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(),false);

    }

    public void setItemClickListner(ItemClickListner itemClickListner) {
        this.itemClickListner = itemClickListner;
    }
}
```

I dont undestart why it show me the Name and the price and quantity are null

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firebase database is giving you `Cart` objects where the `price` and `quantity` is not set. You should ensure that you are setting this attributes where you are loading the records into Firebase.

Comment: I think the attributes are set correctly because I was checking them so many times and the child's name as well.
If it weren't set I think I wouldn't see the name as well.

Comment: I can say that i didnt pay attention . And i Had a space between like "price  "  and that's why it didnt show .

Comment: Thanks alot for the advice .